# Consistency strengths of theories required for physics?

Tags: logic, soft-question, physics, mathematical-physics, proof-theory

1. What are some of the consistency strengths (say, in terms of proof-theoretic ordinals) of the full axiomatizations of the most commonly used theories in physics, for those theories that *have* been fully axiomatized, such as General Relativity, the Standard Model of QM and QFT, etc.?
2. Is there any guess, roughly, as to what level of strength would be required, *at minimum*, for a theory of everything? This is assuming such a thing is eventually possible and ends up not very far off from "quantum gravity."

My motivation for this question is both a) just curiosity about how formalized theories of physics compare to other well-known theories, strength-wise, and b) philosophical (if one believes the universe IS a mathematical structure, or requires a theory describing it to be consistent to exist, this would be, to me, a "reason" to believe in the consistency of theories up to a certain strength.)

Sincerely sorry if this question is too soft for here or would be better on a different stackexchange site, but I couldn't find a better one and couldn't find any information on this question.

Comment: I don't think that axiomatization as used in physics (even mathematical physics) has much to do with proof theory.  On a mathematical level you really don't deal with more than functions of a finite number of real variables, assumed to be as differentiable as necessary (except perhaps for some singularities).

Comment: Does this have anything to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixth_problem

Comment: [The principle states that a universal computing device can simulate every physical process.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church–Turing–Deutsch_principle).

Comment: @CountIblis That may as well be the definition of a universal computing device.  The link itself states that quantum computers can simulated everything modeled by quantum physics, a less trivial claim.  Also less significant since quantum computers are mostly theoretical and there are many different ideas of what a quantum computer is.

Comment: To describe physics you only need universal computation. As barebones theory, Robinson's arithmetic is enough -you can represent proofs of any recursively axiomatized theory in it-, but it's not practical. If you want comfort you'll use ZF at least, choice if you want to talk of big pictures -like study all rings, all varieties, all Lie algebras... So foundations of mathematics are not relevant to physics per se -naturally. Physics only requires ease to formalize things as needed, not working with supertight restrictions. That's a topic in maths, which may interest some physiscists of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the main issue is whether you want to talk about mathematical theories of physics in the normal manner, e.g. using the spectral theorem for arbitrary self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces, or whether you are willing to 'trim down' these theories to algorithms that give approximate predictions, of arbitrary accuracy, for what's observed in specific experiments.

In the former case, where we do mathematically rigorous physics in the ordinary style, we're superficially using ZFC — but we can then work to see if weaker foundations will suffice.  For example, analysts have spent a lot of time working to restate theorems without the need for the Axiom of Choice, and I feel sure physicists could do without it if they wanted.

In the latter case, where we try to take specific theories of physics and strip them down to algorithms for computing approximate predictions given approximate initial data, these algorithms can be expressed in terms of arithmetic (since a rational number can be specified by a pair of integers, and so on), and one can argue that anything beyond recursive functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is not really needed.  There's an extensive theory of ['computable analysis'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis) devoted to these questions:

- Marian B. Pour-El and J. Ian Richards, *Computability in Analysis and Physics*, Springer, Berlin, 1989

and in my undergrad thesis I proved that multiparticle quantum mechanics with Coulomb forces was computable in this sense:

- John C. Baez, [Recursivity in quantum mechanics](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/recursivity.pdf), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **280** (1983), 339–350.

But that's about functions being computable, not theorems being provable.  It would be nice if people took *theorems* about the observable consequences of physical theories and tried to *prove them* using weak foundations.  It's quite possible that something as weak as PRA — [primitive recursive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic) — would suffice!  That has proof-theoretic ordinal $\omega^\omega$.  As you probably know, Harvey Friedman has conjectured that Fermat's Last Theorem can be done proved in [elementary function arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic), which has proof-theoretic ordinal just $\omega^3$.  So far Colin McLarty has shown that finite order arithmetic will suffice:

- Colin McLarty, [The large structures of Grothendieck founded on finite order arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1773).

A similar study for mathematical physics would be interesting, but I'm not aware of it.

After writing the above, I saw this comment by David Roberts on G+:

> I think Feng Ye has shown that a strict version of finitism is enough to capture differential geometry and functional analysis to the point of being able to do relativity and a substantial portion of quantum theory, respectively.

He's referring to this:

- Feng Ye, *Strict Finitism and the Logic of Mathematical Applications*, Springer, Berlin, 2011.  ([Draft version available here](http://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/cllc/people/fengye/finitismAndTheLogicOfMathematicalApplications.pdf).)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I'm a huge fan of yours.

Comment: Thanks.  After your comment I added a link to a draft version of Feng Ye's book - you may want to check that out.

Comment: John, how are you defining consistency strenght to identify it with a countable ordinal?

Comment: More accurately, McLarty has shown that finite-order arithmetic is enough to formalise derived functor cohomology and the required sheaf theory. So essentially Grothendieck's Tohôku paper as well as stuff from SGA4 for which Grothendieck (and Verdier) invoked universes just to play it safe.

Comment: +Andres - maybe "consistency strength" isn't the right term, but since the original questioner said "consistency strengths (say, in terms of proof-theoretic ordinals)", I was mentioning the proof-theoretic ordinals of some theories, defined using [ordinal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis).

Comment: I changed "consistency strength" to "proof-theoretic ordinal" in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, John. (It is what I figured you meant.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, there's a lot of helpful stuff here! (and yeah, conflating proof-theoretic ordinals with measures of consistency strength was my mistake, whoops!)